# Regex match everything after match set except for match set

Tags: javascript, regex

This may be a simple expression to write but I am having the hardest time with this one. I need to match group sets where each group has 2 parts, what we can call the operation and the value. I need the value to match to anything after the operation EXCEPT another operation.

Valid operations to match (standard math operators): `[>,<,=,!,....]`

For example: `'>=25!30<50'` Would result in three matching groups:

`1. (>=, 25)
 2. (!, 30)
 3. (<, 50)`

I can currently solve the above using: `/(>=|<=|>|<|!|=)(\d*)/g` however this only works if the characters in the second match set are numbers.

The wall I am running into is how to match EVERYTHING after EXCEPT for the specified operators.

For example I don't know how to solve: `'<=2017-01-01'` without writing a regex to specify each and every character I would allow (which is anything except the operators) and that just doesn't seem like the correct solution.

There has got to be a way to do this! Thanks guys.

Comment: Probably you want something like `s.split(/([<>=!]=?)/)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

`/((?:>=|<=|>|<|!|=)[^>=<!]+)/g`

the ^ excludes characters you don't want, + means any number of

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
var str = ">=25!30<50";
var pattern = RegExp(/(?:([\<\>\=\!]{1,2})(\d+))/, "g");
var output = [];
let matchs = null;


while((matchs = pattern.exec(str)) != null) {

    output.push([matchs[1], matchs[2]]);
}

console.log(output);
```

Output array :

```
0: Array [ ">=", "25" ]
​
1: Array [ "!", "30" ]
​
2: Array [ "<", "50" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you might do is match the operations `(>=|<=|>|<|!|=)` which will be the first of the 2 parts and in a capturing group use a negative lookahead to match while there is not an operation directly at the right side which will be the second of the 2 parts.

[`(?:>=|<=|>|<|!|=)((?:(?!(?:>=|<=|>|<|!|=)).)+)`](https://regex101.com/r/cQFh1R/1/)

- `(?:>=|<=|>|<|!|=)` Match one of the operations using an alternation
- `(` Start capturing group (This will contain your value)

  - `(?:` Start non capturing group

    - `(?!(?:>=|<=|>|<|!|=)).` Negative lookahead which asserts what is on the right side is not an operation and matches any character `.`
  - `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat one or more times
- `)` Close capturing group

```js
const regex = /(?:>=|<=|>|<|!|=)((?:(?!(?:>=|<=|>|<|!|=)).)+)/gm;
const strings = [
  ">=25!30<50",
  ">=test!30<$@#%",
  "34"
];
let m;

strings.forEach((s) => {
  while ((m = regex.exec(s)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
      regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    console.log(m[1]);
  }
});
```